# Nested array within nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had an object whose structure is

```
const data = {
    "message": "fetch responces successfully",
    "responce": [
        {
            "created_AT": "Mon, 03 Jan 2022 17:39:24 GMT",
            "created_BY": "avinash",
            "dateTime": "Mon, 03 Jan 2022 17:39:24 GMT",
            "deleted_BY": "",
            "flag": 0,
            "project_ID": "infobot1234",
            "responce": {
                "uttence_test_heading": [
                    {
                        "buttons": [
                            {
                                "payload": "/my_localities",
                                "title": "savings"
                            },
                            {
                                "payload": "/my_localities12333qqqwq",
                                "title": "current"
                            },
                            {
                                "payload": "/fruits",
                                "title": "platinum"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Test Heading"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "responce_ID": "6bbb20d6-7f71-408a-a78a-bab39a30016f",
            "responce_name": "uttence_test_heading",
            "updated_BY": "",
            "user_ID": "av1234"
        },
        {
            "created_AT": "Tue, 04 Jan 2022 17:49:36 GMT",
            "created_BY": "avinash",
            "dateTime": "Tue, 04 Jan 2022 17:49:36 GMT",
            "deleted_BY": "",
            "flag": 0,
            "project_ID": "infobot1234",
            "responce": {
                "utter_content": [
                    {
                        "text": "text_title for buttonqwqwq"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "responce_ID": "81d699ee-3e78-4356-b703-af095d91e36b",
            "responce_name": "utter_txt1234",
            "updated_BY": "",
            "user_ID": "av1234"
        },
        {
            "created_AT": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 18:06:39 GMT",
            "created_BY": "avinash",
            "dateTime": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 18:06:39 GMT",
            "deleted_BY": "",
            "flag": 0,
            "project_ID": "infobot1234",
            "responce": {
                "uttence_text_heading": [
                    {
                        "buttons": [
                            {
                                "payload": "/my_localities",
                                "title": "savings"
                            },
                            {
                                "payload": "/my_localities12333qqqwq",
                                "title": "current"
                            },
                            {
                                "payload": "/test",
                                "title": "premium"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Text Heading"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "responce_ID": "bb6b0005-bbd4-49a1-8b25-58e0768800a1",
            "responce_name": "uttence_text_heading",
            "updated_BY": "",
            "user_ID": "av1234"
        },
        {
            "created_AT": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 20:13:54 GMT",
            "created_BY": "avinash",
            "dateTime": "Thu, 13 Jan 2022 20:13:54 GMT",
            "deleted_BY": "",
            "flag": 0,
            "project_ID": "infobot1234",
            "responce": {
                "uttence_heading_test": [
                    {
                        "buttons": [
                            {
                                "payload": "/my_localities",
                                "title": "savings"
                            },
                            {
                                "payload": "/fruits",
                                "title": "current"
                            },
                            {
                                "payload": "/undefined",
                                "title": "premium"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "heading test"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "responce_ID": "7aeb2a42-a5f8-464d-832d-47cee4cfdb38",
            "responce_name": "uttence_heading_test",
            "updated_BY": "",
            "user_ID": "av1234"
        }
    ],
    "status_code": 0
}
```

I was able to extract below array of objects by using `data.responce.map(responce => responce.responce)`

```
[{
  uttence_test_heading: [{
  buttons: [{
  payload: "/my_localities",
  title: "savings"
}, {
  payload: "/my_localities12333qqqwq",
  title: "current"
}, {
  payload: "/fruits",
  title: "platinum"
}]
}, {
  title: "Test Heading"
}]
}, {
  utter_content: [{
  text: "text_title for buttonqwqwq"
}]
}, {
  uttence_text_heading: [{
  buttons: [{
  payload: "/my_localities",
  title: "savings"
}, {
  payload: "/my_localities12333qqqwq",
  title: "current"
}, {
  payload: "/test",
  title: "premium"
}]
}, {
  title: "Text Heading"
}]
}, {
  uttence_heading_test: [{
  buttons: [{
  payload: "/my_localities",
  title: "savings"
}, {
  payload: "/fruits",
  title: "current"
}, {
  payload: "/undefined",
  title: "premium"
}]
}, {
  title: "heading test"
}]
}]
```

Now I want to construct an array of objects whose structure is something like below

This is my expected result, but I am stuck since the uttence_name is a key and it is different for each object so could someone please guide me through how can I acheive my expected result. Please Help !

```
[{uttence_name: ' uttence_test_heading',buttons: ['savings','current','platinum'],text: '',responce_ID:'6bbb20d6-7f71-408a-a78a-bab39a30016f'},
{uttence_name: 'utter_content',buttons: '',text: 'text_title for buttonqwqwq',responce_ID:'81d699ee-3e78-4356-b703-af095d91e36b'},
{uttence_name:'uttence_text_heading',buttons:['savings','current','premium'],text: '',responce_ID:'bb6b0005-bbd4-49a1-8b25-58e0768800a1'}]
```

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JavaScript. Is `buttons` indented to be an array? Then surround all those strings with square brackets, also `''` to be consistent, or even better: an empty array. Note that JS has a specific value for the *absence* of a value, and it is not the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain a second `map` and obtain the desired result. But my answer assumes that the arrays only have a single item in them.

Also, I didn't quite understand what you wanted to do with the `buttons` so I've kept them as an array.

*You can run the snippet below to see if you're getting the desired output.*

```js
const data={message:"fetch responces successfully",responce:[{created_AT:"Mon, 03 Jan 2022 17:39:24 GMT",created_BY:"avinash",dateTime:"Mon, 03 Jan 2022 17:39:24 GMT",deleted_BY:"",flag:0,project_ID:"infobot1234",responce:{uttence_test_heading:[{buttons:[{payload:"/my_localities",title:"savings",},{payload:"/my_localities12333qqqwq",title:"current",},{payload:"/fruits",title:"platinum",},],},{title:"Test Heading",},],},responce_ID:"6bbb20d6-7f71-408a-a78a-bab39a30016f",responce_name:"uttence_test_heading",updated_BY:"",user_ID:"av1234",},{created_AT:"Tue, 04 Jan 2022 17:49:36 GMT",created_BY:"avinash",dateTime:"Tue, 04 Jan 2022 17:49:36 GMT",deleted_BY:"",flag:0,project_ID:"infobot1234",responce:{utter_content:[{text:"text_title for buttonqwqwq",},],},responce_ID:"81d699ee-3e78-4356-b703-af095d91e36b",responce_name:"utter_txt1234",updated_BY:"",user_ID:"av1234",},{created_AT:"Thu, 13 Jan 2022 18:06:39 GMT",created_BY:"avinash",dateTime:"Thu, 13 Jan 2022 18:06:39 GMT",deleted_BY:"",flag:0,project_ID:"infobot1234",responce:{uttence_text_heading:[{buttons:[{payload:"/my_localities",title:"savings",},{payload:"/my_localities12333qqqwq",title:"current",},{payload:"/test",title:"premium",},],},{title:"Text Heading",},],},responce_ID:"bb6b0005-bbd4-49a1-8b25-58e0768800a1",responce_name:"uttence_text_heading",updated_BY:"",user_ID:"av1234",},{created_AT:"Thu, 13 Jan 2022 20:13:54 GMT",created_BY:"avinash",dateTime:"Thu, 13 Jan 2022 20:13:54 GMT",deleted_BY:"",flag:0,project_ID:"infobot1234",responce:{uttence_heading_test:[{buttons:[{payload:"/my_localities",title:"savings",},{payload:"/fruits",title:"current",},{payload:"/undefined",title:"premium",},],},{title:"heading test",},],},responce_ID:"7aeb2a42-a5f8-464d-832d-47cee4cfdb38",responce_name:"uttence_heading_test",updated_BY:"",user_ID:"av1234",},],status_code:0,}

const result = data.responce
  .map((res) => ({...res.responce, responce_ID: res.responce_ID }))
  .map((obj) => ({
    utterance_name: Object.keys(obj)[0],
    text: Object.values(obj)[0][0].text || "",
    buttons: Object.values(obj)[0][0].buttons?.map((btn) => btn.title) || "",
    responce_ID: obj.responce_ID
  }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works but what If I want the responce_ID as well, I forgot to mention that in my question and I have edited it just now

Comment: @Sachin I've updated my answer to include `responce_ID` as well, please take a look

Comment: @Sachin, A friendly reminder: there would be an bug if the order of  buttons, text ,title are not always the same in the array. For example, if buttons in order 0 and text in order 1.

Comment: @ikhvjs Order is as such not necessary in my case, the data is coming from an api endpoint and I have to display that in an ant design table which uses only an array of objects to display the data that's why I wanted to construct array of objects in which I have only 4 fields the responce_ID is needed if a  user wants to delete the utterance

Comment: @Sachin, This data `uttence_text_heading: [
                    { title: "Text Heading" },
                    { text: "text_title for buttonqwqwq" },
                ],` and this data `uttence_text_heading: [
                    { text: "text_title for buttonqwqwq" },
                    { title: "Text Heading" },
                ],` will yield different result from this solution.

Comment: @ikhvjs But we can assume that the data model is intact, there are changes that would break all the solutions here, just because your solution solves this special case doesn't mean its better. What the are chances that this will happen, what if its sure that this would never be the case?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee, that's why I said friendly remind and I add assumption for OP to consider.

Comment: @ikhvjs as I mentioned I have to display this data to ant design table, which figures out the order itself so even if it is not ordered as you are saying then it doesn't matter because that case is not handled by me its handled by ant design, but thanks for a friendly heads up I appreciate it.

Comment: @Sachin, thanks for the feedback. However, I still don't understand why it doesn't matter, if the order from the endpoint is changed, and you use this solution, it will yeild different results and if you use the different result for the ant design table, the design table will still show the same thing?

Comment: @ikhvjs
  Yes As long as the object key is correct it will display properly

Comment: @Sachin Correct! It would work properly! You don't need to unnecessarily complicate the solution.

Comment: @Sachin, but the value is not correct… anyway, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the required result based upon the data you have given. In the code, the best case scenario is, **it checks whether you have object containing text or not and then adds the data accordingly**. It also has **response_ID**

```js
const data={message:"fetch responces successfully",responce:[{created_AT:"Mon, 03 Jan 2022 17:39:24 GMT",created_BY:"avinash",dateTime:"Mon, 03 Jan 2022 17:39:24 GMT",deleted_BY:"",flag:0,project_ID:"infobot1234",responce:{uttence_test_heading:[{buttons:[{payload:"/my_localities",title:"savings",},{payload:"/my_localities12333qqqwq",title:"current",},{payload:"/fruits",title:"platinum",},],},{title:"Test Heading",},],},responce_ID:"6bbb20d6-7f71-408a-a78a-bab39a30016f",responce_name:"uttence_test_heading",updated_BY:"",user_ID:"av1234",},{created_AT:"Tue, 04 Jan 2022 17:49:36 GMT",created_BY:"avinash",dateTime:"Tue, 04 Jan 2022 17:49:36 GMT",deleted_BY:"",flag:0,project_ID:"infobot1234",responce:{utter_content:[{text:"text_title for buttonqwqwq",},],},responce_ID:"81d699ee-3e78-4356-b703-af095d91e36b",responce_name:"utter_txt1234",updated_BY:"",user_ID:"av1234",},{created_AT:"Thu, 13 Jan 2022 18:06:39 GMT",created_BY:"avinash",dateTime:"Thu, 13 Jan 2022 18:06:39 GMT",deleted_BY:"",flag:0,project_ID:"infobot1234",responce:{uttence_text_heading:[{buttons:[{payload:"/my_localities",title:"savings",},{payload:"/my_localities12333qqqwq",title:"current",},{payload:"/test",title:"premium",},],},{title:"Text Heading",},],},responce_ID:"bb6b0005-bbd4-49a1-8b25-58e0768800a1",responce_name:"uttence_text_heading",updated_BY:"",user_ID:"av1234",},{created_AT:"Thu, 13 Jan 2022 20:13:54 GMT",created_BY:"avinash",dateTime:"Thu, 13 Jan 2022 20:13:54 GMT",deleted_BY:"",flag:0,project_ID:"infobot1234",responce:{uttence_heading_test:[{buttons:[{payload:"/my_localities",title:"savings",},{payload:"/fruits",title:"current",},{payload:"/undefined",title:"premium",},],},{title:"heading test",},],},responce_ID:"7aeb2a42-a5f8-464d-832d-47cee4cfdb38",responce_name:"uttence_heading_test",updated_BY:"",user_ID:"av1234",},],status_code:0,};

let newObject = [];
data.responce.forEach((item) => {
    // We will get each item here now
    // Assuming object of item.responce will come always
    const objectName = Object.keys(item.responce)[0];
    const dataToPush = {
      'responce_ID': item.responce_ID,
      'uttence_name': objectName,
      'buttons': item.responce[objectName][0].buttons ? item.responce[objectName][0].buttons.map(data => data.title) : '',
      'text': item.responce[objectName].find(data => data.hasOwnProperty('text')) ? item.responce[objectName].map(value => value.text)[0] : ''
    };
    // Finally adding the item to the array to give the final output
    newObject.push(dataToPush);
});

console.log(newObject);
```

Comment: @Sachin take a look at this answer, as it is somehow improved version of all the solution. Do let me know if that also solves your problem with more efficiency